# How start ejabberdctl from bash script properly?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ejabberd

I need to register many thousands of users in ejabberd from csv file. For this, I wrote a simple script.

```
#!/bin/sh
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read username domain pass p1 p2 p3 p4
do
    echo "ejabberdctl register $username $domain $pass"
    ejabberdctl register $username $domain $pass
done < users.csv
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

But in the end, the answer is: Error: cannot_register
If I just run the line copied from the output, everything is ok. The user is created normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a little trick for later: once you get your loop working, if you consider *ejabberdctl* is too slow, you can try using the ReST API. That should be a lot faster when doing many requests.

Configure temporarily something like this (remember to remove this when you finished):

```
listen:
  -
    port: 5280
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: false 
    request_handlers:
      /api: mod_http_api

api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
      - mod_http_api
    who: all
    what: "*"

modules:
  mod_http_api: {}
```

Then execute this in a shell to register an account:

```
curl 'localhost:5280/api/register?user=user2&host=localhost&password=somepass123'
```